# Is there a way to track installed Chrome Plugins across the organization

Tags: powershell, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to find a way to track installs of plugins in chrome in our organization is it possible in any way via powershell or any specific app or any plugin. I have researched and checked but I Think it is only possible via Enterprise edition correct me if I am wrong with this.

Comment: I've got a script that does this I can check for. There's a text file in Chrome that has the data, I used the script to write that data into WMI, then use a custom MOF so CM12 imports the data during the inventory collection. Of course, once you have the data out of the text file, you could store it wherever you prefer. Google Admin Console, of course, makes this ridiculously easy.

Comment: I will have to ask management for permission for the google console as it is paid.
Are you willing to share the script? and does it cover laptop or also mobile devices that has chrome.

Comment: Also just to add and ask if I may WMI has been enabled on all your computers for this to work right?

Comment: Yeah, I'll post some stuff tomorrow when I get to work. Only covers Windows machines, as it's PowerShell. My version doesn't use remote WMI, which is probably what you have disabled- but just using it as a temporary storage method until CM12 collects the data into a single database. You could write it directly to a DB or even log it to a spreadsheet.

Comment: Hi Mark any updates on this sorry for the rush as I need this for our MDM if possible thanks in advance.